# How to bring UWP app from background (minimized mode) to foreground programmatically?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have tried lots of options to bring the UWP app from minimized mode to foreground (Top of all running app) programmatically but not succeeded at all :(, here are the options I have tried to do the same as follow:-

1: code:-
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("yourprotocolhere://"));`

it launches but not able to bring the in the foreground but it makes the app blinking in the taskbar.

2  code: -
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
{
ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

```
                // Get the root frame
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
                // just ensure that the window is active
                if (rootFrame == null)
                {
                    // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                    rootFrame = new Frame();

                    rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                    if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                    {
                        //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                    }
                    // Place the frame in the current Window
                    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                }
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AppRootContainer));
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

Resulted same as above one.

3: I have even tried to desktop extension with restricted capability "runFullTrust" to launch/bring the app in the foreground but still not succeeded..

Can anyone guide me to achieve the same or want to know is it possible to in UWP (bring the app in front of the screen, if app was minimized or hidden behind other apps automatically) ?

Any help would really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also used ExtendedExecutionSession to prevent the app to go in suspended mode :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have even tried to desktop extension with restricted capability "runFullTrust" to launch/bring the app in the foreground but still not succeeded

Above thread is correct, we could get current app's [entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.getapplistentriesasync?view=winrt-19041) then call `LaunchAsync` method to launch UWP app within desktop extension.

```
IEnumerable<AppListEntry> appListEntries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();
```

For more detail please research stefan's blog **Global hotkey registration in UWP**.

Comment: Have tried this with desktop extension, still app is blinking in taskbar not coming in the foreground :(

Comment: Please check stefan's code sample, when you press `Alt + S`, uwp app will come into foreground.

Comment: Yes it comes in the foreground provided no other app gets opened (Showing desktop) but if one or more app are being in foreground then my app blinking in the taskbar not coming in the foreground.

Comment: For my testing it could come into foreground even if other apps has been in the [foreground](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYFyfA9K4oLu2SXng?e=KUhVcr).

Comment: As i Know that it comes into the foreground, I did sometime with me, but when we open an app having input text box and focus on that means click at least once in the input text box this is the condition when app does not come into the foreground.

Comment: @manigupta. I have tested above scenario, And `appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync()` still works well, could you test with other computer to exclude system issue?

Comment: I have tested with other system, App comes foreground when other apps are focused..if focused then app launched using "appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync()"  programmatically (no user intervention mean by done by any button )but just blinking in the taskbar not coming into foreground of other apps..



Could you please test this as described in the my comment..

Comment: This is testing [record](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYFyfA9K4oLu2SXng?e=eeCWzi) please check.

Comment: have you launched the app by button click or automatically by code (using like timer)?
because it works perfectly when user click the any key or button but not automatically..

See, My project like a screen saver when user lefts the system idle for some time then our app has to come automatically after a time elapsed in the foreground and play something like linage

Comment: Can you please send a sample what you have recorded ?

Comment: Yep, I call app to foreground with keyboard Alt + S. Calling app into foreground is user action, if you call it with code or time. system will use  blinking to told user the app want to foreground then need user confirm this. it's by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220623/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-mani-gupta).

Comment: Many thanks @Nico for understanding my concerns, yes it can be launched into the foreground but if you call it by time then blinking...

Have any idea to bring the app into foreground by calling it by time ?